# How do I populate my imageViews with different images from my imageArray instead of setting the same image for each imageView?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop, uiimageview

I basically have 2 view controllers: a camera view controller and a detail view controller. Each time I take a picture, I want to add it to my detail view controller, which can hold up to 4 imageViews. Below is my code for the detail view controller.

My images are added to my imageArray and I am trying to distribute them to my 4 imageViews, as displayed below. What is hapening is that the same image from the image array is being set to all 4 imageViews (as each imageView.image == nil). Does anyone know how to change this so that each imageView is populated by the next image in the imageArray?

```
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    for img in imageArray {
        if imageArray.count < imageViewArray.count || imageArray.count == imageViewArray.count {
            for imgV in imageViewArray {
                if imgV.image == nil {
                    imgV.image = img
                }
            }
    }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason all 4 `imageView`s contain the same `image` is because on the first iteration every `imageView`'s `image` property is nil and you're assigning the first `image` in the `imageArray` to every `imageView` with a nil `image`.

You could use one for loop like so:

```
for (imageView, image) in zip(imageViewArray, imageArray)
{
    imageView.image = image
}
```

The zip function will combine the two arrays in to tuples (imageView, image). Please take note that the zip function will ignore any images after the 4th element since there are only 4 imageViews and vice versa if there are less images than imageViews. This means that only the first four images in the imageArray will be used, which based on the code in your question, seems like what you want.

[zip(_ :_ :)](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:FSs3zipu0_Rq_Ss12SequenceTypeq0_S__FTq_q0__GVSs12Zip2Sequenceq_q0__)

> A sequence of pairs built out of two underlying sequences, where the
>   elements of the ith pair are the ith elements of each underlying
>   sequence.

Comment: Although C-style `for` loops are a part of Swift it's increasingly preferred to use the `for...in` style. (There's talk of the C-style `for` loops being removed from the language.) If you need an index you can iterate on the `enumerate()` function: `for (index, value) in imageViewArray.enumerate() { }`

Comment: @KennethBruno: Oh, cool. Thanks for the info! I probably should have mentioned in the answer that the code is from an ObjC stand point. I haven't started learning Swift, yet.

Comment: I saw the Objective-C in your answer. The question is tagged Swift so answers should use Swift code, if possible. Give the language a try when you get a chance. It's very simple to learn if you already know Objective-C and, to me at least, seems great to work with.

Comment: Thanks guys, can you not use this variation of for-loops in Swift? For some reason I am still struggling to get this wired up right

Comment: @JamieBaker, I've added a swift version of the code. This should work just fine.

Comment: @JamieBaker, Also, C-style for loops are going to be removed in Swift 3.0 as there are more advanced and cleaner solutions. So, try to refrain from using them.

Comment: @Jonathan thanks for letting me know. this current code is causing this crash: 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'. This crash is happening when I try and add my image to my imageArray by hitting my 'yes' button on a still captured image

Comment: @Jonathan the issue is that you retrieve 4 index variables but if you only take 2 pictures, then it crashes because you are indexing 4 for an array that only contains 2 variables - is there a way around this?

Comment: @JamieBaker, see my edit. I've changed the swift code to use a pretty cool function I just found that should work for you. Basically, it combines the two arrays in to tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified example using mocked classes:

```
class MockImage {
  init(_ value:Int) {
    self.value = value
  }
  var value:Int = 0
}

class MockView {
  var image:MockImage?
}

let imageArray = [MockImage(1),MockImage(3),MockImage(5)]
var imgViewArray = [MockView?]()
for _ in 0...3 {
  imgViewArray.append(MockView())
}

// Example code starts here
var sequence = imageArray.generate()
for case let imgV? in imgViewArray where imgV.image == nil {
  if let image = sequence.next() {
      imgV.image = image
  }
}
```

If any of the images in the views are `nil` then they will be assigned the next available image from `imageArray`

Comment: Thanks Kenneth, this code doesn't actually work. The imageViews remain blank when instead of populating. Any reason for this do you reckon?

Comment: This shows the technique of filling an array with data in the manner you asked about, you have to change the data values and types to match what you are dealing with. Are you doing that?

Comment: My current imageViewArray is initialised in viewdidload and contains the 4 imageViews. My imageArray is populated as and when I add an image from my cameraViewController. On that basis, which arrays here need updating would you say?

Comment: I cleaned up the code a bit and added a mock view and mock image class just to show how it should work. Use the code from `var sequence = imageArray.generate()` and down in your function.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth, still can't get this to run. I am actually implementing the mock classes (is that right or should I replace with my custom values) and then running the exmaple code in the function. Not seeming to work - feel like I may be being quite stupid here and missing something fairly simple

Comment: Replace with the real classes. The mocks are there so the example can run in a playground without requiring the rest of your code. You can probably just put the code below "// Example..." in your `viewWillAppear` function, assuming the variable names match up correctly.